# SQL Check Constraint Based on Counts

Tags: sql, sql-server, check-constraints

I have the following table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE saved_custom_view (
[saved_custom_view_id]  BIGINT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,        
[user_id]               BIGINT          NULL,   
[name]                  NVARCHAR (250)  NOT NULL,
[is_default_view]       BIT             NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
CONSTRAINT [PK__saved_custom_view] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([saved_custom_view_id] ASC),    
CONSTRAINT [FK__saved_custom_view__user] FOREIGN KEY ([user_id]) REFERENCES [user] ([user_id]),
```

);

I want to make sure that no user has more than one row with is_default_value set to true.  Therefore, the second insert here should be prevented with a proper CHECK CONSTRAINT.

```
insert into saved_custom_view values (1, 'test', 1)
insert into saved_custom_view values (1, 'test', 1)
```

How do I write a check constraint for this?

```
ALTER TABLE saved_custom_view
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_no_user_has_duplicate_default_views CHECK (
    -- what goes here?
);
```

Or is there a way to do a unique check against multiple columns?

Comment: You should tag your question with the appropriate database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use a filtered unique index:

```
create unique index idx_save_custom_view_u1 on
    saved_custom_view(user_id, is_default_value)
    where is_default_value = 1;
```

These are described in more detail [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx).